# How to simulate a serial port failure?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

Working on a library which communicates with a range of USB devices I want to develop a suite of API tests to check the integration status of new devices. One of the situations I wish to test is unexpected device removal. Short of creating breakpoints in the test script where the device must be manually unplugged/replugged I would like to be able to simulate this behaviour programattically.

Currently I am simulating this with [Devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) but the problem I am facing is that if the API has already connected to the device on an open serial port Devcon cannot close that serial port and so I cannot fully simulate device removal, even though all of the devices manifestations in Device Manager apart from the remaining COM port are removed.

I have been unable to find a solution in my research effort so far, and wondered if anyone had encountered the same problem/knows of a solution.

(Language is c#, .Net2.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might be not exactly an answer to your question, but I would do the following:
Refactor every access to real hardware/devices into interfaces and inject them as dependencies into your code.
Now you can mock those interfaces and do unit-testing as you like.

To make integration/real test to the real thing and indeed unplug/plug, etc. the hard way.

This works fine for me and for many others I think.

Comment: The purpose of the API tests are to communicate with actual devices which haven't been properly integrated yet and identify what work needs to be done to achieve compliance, so mocking hardware is not really an option. I don't think you could really call it 'Unit Testing' anyway. Thanks anyway.

Comment: ok - sorry the API test sliped my notice. But in this case I really think you either have to simulate the hardware and physical connections in some kind of physical lab environment. Even if you could use software to set/remove connections there is no way for you to tell if this do behave the same way as a real disconnect will ...